# Use componentRestrictions to just one state in Google Maps

Tags: google-maps

I am trying to use `componentRestrictions` in Google Places autocomplete. I can restrict by country, but when I try to restrict by administrative area, the whole thing crashes.

```js
var options = {
    componentRestrictions: { administrativeArea: 'TX' }
};

var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);

google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function () {
    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
    if (!place.geometry) {
        return;
    }

    var address = '';
    if (place.address_components) {
        address = [
          (place.address_components[0] && place.address_components[0].short_name || ''),
          (place.address_components[1] && place.address_components[1].short_name || ''),
          (place.address_components[2] && place.address_components[2].short_name || '')
        ].join(' ');
    }

});
```

Comment: how did you resolved the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am afraid you can’t, because [Google Maps only accept country as a filter](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#ComponentRestrictions).

Comment: I believe what the OP is trying to do should be a feature but couldn't find the feature request. If someone finds it please let me know and I will star it.

Answer (score 0):

You can create geofence by Lat Lang values:
Like

```
`var center = { lat: 12.9716, lng: 77.5946 };
// Create a bounding box with sides ~80km away from the center point
const defaultBounds = {
  north: center.lat + 0.8,
  south: center.lat - 0.8,
  east: center.lng + 0.8,
  west: center.lng - 0.8,
};
var options = {
  bounds: defaultBounds,
  componentRestrictions: { country: "IN" },
  strictBounds: true,
  types: ["(cities)"],
};`
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//replace api key
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY_HERE&libraries=places"></script>

//replace center location latlng
var center = { lat: --37.817282, lng: 144.962297 };
            // Create a bounding box with sides ~80km away from the center point
            const defaultBounds = {
              north: center.lat + 0.8,
              south: center.lat - 0.8,
              east: center.lng + 0.8,
              west: center.lng - 0.8,
            };

        /* Create address autocomplete */
          var autocompleteOptions = {
            bounds: defaultBounds,
            strictBounds: true,
            types: ['address'],
            // restrict to only Aussie addresses - change 'au' to any other 2-letter country code as you please
            componentRestrictions: {country: 'au'}
          };

          function initAutocomplete() {
            // Change the ID on the line below as required
            var input = document.getElementById('delivery_address');
            console.log(autocompleteOptions);
            autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, autocompleteOptions);
            console.log(autocomplete);
            // Uncomment the line below if you wish to call the fillInAddress example function on user selection
            autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', fillInAddress);
          }
          google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initAutocomplete);
          var componentForm = {
            street_number: 'short_name',
            route: 'long_name',
            locality: 'long_name',
            administrative_area_level_1: 'short_name',
            country: 'long_name',
            postal_code: 'short_name'
          };

          function fillInAddress() {
            var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
            var selectedAdd = $('#delivery_address').val();
            if (place.geometry) {
              var addressObj = {};
              for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
                var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
                var val = place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
                addressObj[addressType] = val;
              }
              //addressObj.street_number ? $('#address-address-1').val(addressObj.street_number + ' ' + addressObj.route) : $('#address-address-1').val(addressObj.route);
               selectedAdd = selectedAdd.split(",");
              selectedAdd = selectedAdd[0];
              $('#delivery_address').val(selectedAdd);
              $('#delivery_suburb').val(addressObj.locality);
              $('#delivery_state').val(addressObj.administrative_area_level_1);//State
              $('#delivery_postcode').val(addressObj.postal_code);
              $('#address-country').val(addressObj.country);    

            } else {
              alert("Something went wrong. Please try again.");
            }
          }
```

Thanks to @Mahesan Rv

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).