# Google maps API Autocomplete: output only cities of specific state

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, ionic3

I'm developing cab booking app using `ionic-3 framework`. I have used `Google maps API` Autocomplete in my app and its working fine but i want to display cities and place of only specific state (my cab service is only available for my state Maharashtra). can you please suggest me how to do this. My code integration is following. Thank you.

```
 <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_API_KEY&libraries=places"></script>

 this.GoogleAutocomplete = new google.maps.places.AutocompleteService();
 SearchAddress() {
    if (this.autocompleteFrom.input == '') {
      this.autocompleteItemsFrom = [];
      return;
    }
    this.GoogleAutocomplete.getPlacePredictions({ input: this.autocompleteFrom.input },
      (predictions, status) => {
        this.autocompleteItemsFrom = [];
        this.zone.run(() => {
          predictions.forEach((prediction) => {
            this.autocompleteItemsFrom.push(prediction);
          });
        });
      });
  }
```

Comment: You can't filter by state, only by country: https://stackoverflow.com/q/26510984/863110

Answer (score 0):

You can bias results toward the area you are interested in using location and radius parameters or alternatively bounds parameter in the request.

Have a look at the documentation

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/places-autocomplete-service#AutocompletionRequest.

Unfortunately, autocomplete service doesn't support strict bounds at the moment, so you cannot restrict results to specified area exactly.

The corresponding feature request for strict bounds was created in Google issue tracker:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36219203

I can suggest staring the feature request to add your vote and subscribe to further notifications.

Resuming, your code should be changed to something like

```
this.GoogleAutocomplete.getPlacePredictions({ 
    input: this.autocompleteFrom.input,
    bounds: {
        east: 80.890924,
        north: 22.028441,
        south: 15.6024121,
        west: 72.659363
    } 
  },
  (predictions, status) => {
    this.autocompleteItemsFrom = [];
    this.zone.run(() => {
      predictions.forEach((prediction) => {
        this.autocompleteItemsFrom.push(prediction);
      });
    });
  });
```

In this example I used bounds that returns Geocoding API for Maharashtra state

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Maharashtra&key=MY_API_KEY`

```
....
formatted_address: "Maharashtra, India",
geometry: {
    bounds: {
        northeast: {
           lat: 22.028441,
           lng: 80.890924
        },
        southwest: {
           lat: 15.6024121,
           lng: 72.659363
        }
    },
    location: {
        lat: 19.7514798,
        lng: 75.7138884
    },
    .....
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your reply but it's not working fo me.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is the best approach that you can use with service. Consider using `google.maps.places.Autocomplete` widget instead of service. The autocomplete widget allows to use [strict bounds](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/places-widget#AutocompleteOptions).

Comment: can you please suggest me how can i implement it in my code.

Comment: Google has examples. Have a look at https://developers-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete